# Express exponential reachability in graphs

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic, modal-logic

In first-order logic in the language of graphs, can one express that there is a pair of nodes connected by a path of length $2^m-1$ using **only** $\leq m$ quantifiers?

My question comes from the point of view of modal logic and bisimulation. In the context of a particular proof of the van Benthem-Rosen result, one shows that a first-order formula of quantifier-rank $m$ is $2^m-1$-bisimulation invariant.

Now, in the literature I am reading, it is claimed that the bound is sharp and that an example of a formula of quantifier-rank $\leq m$ which is bisimulation invariant but not $l$-bisimulation invariant for $l<2^m-1$ can be found by considering reachability in graphs involving exponential length as above. I can't make it out, however.

Comment: The exponential growth seems right, but the exact value $2^m-1$ doesn't work. For $m=1$, how can you express "there is a pair of nodes connected by an edge" (an edge is a path of length $1$) using only one quantifier? (Also, you might want to clarify if the path is meant to have all distinct vertices, since that condition might be tough to encode.)

Comment: Just as a reflection. Given a finite graph $G$, we may at least say there is an equivalent formula with $\leq m$ quantifiers for almost all $m$, i.e. **F** if $2^m>|V(G)|$. On the other hand, if the minimal degree of $G$ is $\geq3$ and the Erdős-Gyárfás conjecture is true, then $G$ contains a cycle of some length $2^m$ (thus, a path of length $2^m-1$). For this $m$, we have an equivalent formula **T** with $\leq m$ quantifiers.

Comment: Does the language of graphs consist of just a predicate symbol $R : V \times V \to 2$ indicating whether vertices are connected? Or is there a sort of edges and some kind of incidence relation? Also, is the graph directed or undirected? Also, self-edges definitively ruled out?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but locality of first order logic may be relevant. Also, I suppose you mean quantifier rank $\leq m$ formula instead of using $\leq m$ quantifiers, right?.